# /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found

Tags: c++, gcc, libstdc++

How can I get GLIBCXX_3.4.15 in Ubuntu? I can't run some programs that I'm compiling.

When I do:

```
strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
```

I get:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 81, accepted):

I'm compiling gcc 4.6 from source, and apparently

```
sudo make install
```

didn't catch this one. I dug around and found

```
gcc/trunk/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6.0.15
```

I copied it in to /usr/lib and redirected libstdc++.so.6 to point to the new one, and now everything works.

Comment: This works with gcc 4.6.2 as well except it's libstdc++.so.6.0.16.  Thanks!

Comment: Mine is gcc 4.7 and libstdc++.so.6.0.17. Had the same problem, fixed with this solution. Kudos.

Comment: Is there a way around this without having to manually compile gcc?  Like a simple `apt-get` command, perhaps?

Comment: Yes, there is.  An `apt-get` based solution to this problem is described here:  http://superuser.com/questions/310809/how-can-i-update-gcc-to-the-latest-version-in-ubuntu-10-04

Comment: This lame error has been tormenting CENTOS/Ubuntu/Linux users for a while now. And why exactly the developers of these OSs did not bother with a fix or an update??

Thanks for the fix btw :)!

Comment: @roosevelt: it's not a problem with the OS, it's a problem with users installing software themselves then not using the linker correctly. It's a FAQ: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

Comment: Thanks @Chris. your solution works for me.  It takes couple of minutes to generate libstdc++.so.6.0.15

Comment: In my case, I copied /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 into /usr/lib and then I soft linked /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.15 (replace by the one your program needs) to that.

Answer (score 63):

I have been avoiding this issue in the past by simply linking libstdc++ statically with this parameter sent to g++ when linking my executable:

```
-static-libstdc++
```

If linking in the library statically is an option this is probably the quickest work-around.

Comment: The problem is that the library cannot be found, not that you should statically link. See the answer from @Hobo.

Comment: This is helpful when you are out of the default make system and just want to have a POC on small code. There is no harm in statically linking a small code where size of binary...blah blah.... doesn't matter.  Quick and easy fix

Answer (score 50):

I was trying to get clang to work (which also requires 6.0.15), and while poking around I found it was installed at `/usr/local/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.15`. It installed there when I installed graphite (an experimental gcc version).

If you need access to libraries at that location, then you’ll need to define `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as:

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib64`

I was able to get clang to work after doing this. Hope that is helpful to someone.

Comment: I was working on an embedded target and i get the same problem, your solution seems not to work in my case. In fact most of the binary in the target uses the default c library in /lib, so changing `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` will affect them. they will all link to the new library, In the end most of the binaries are not working: such as `ls` `grep`,....: I'am getting : `ls: error while loading shared libraries: libc.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 15):

I encounter this problem when trying to use matlab eng to call m functions from c code.
which occurs with command `mex -f .. ..`

My solution:

```
strings /usr/lib/i386-<tab>/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
```

I found it includes 3.4.15

so my system has the newest libs.

the problem comes from matlab itself, it calls its own libstdc++.so.6 from `{MATLAB}/bin`

so, just replace it with the updated system lib.

Comment: This seems to also work for me in Matlab 2013b x64 on Xubuntu 13.04 x64

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just had to create a new symbolic link for the file in `{MATLAB}/bin` to the file in `/usr/lib/`, and then to **restart** matlab. This works in Matlab 2010b on Fedora 14 x64.

Comment: This worked for me when dealing with Lattice Radiant and prjoxide / nextpnr.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you don't control the target machine (e.g. your library needs to run on a locked-down enterprise system). In such a case you will need to recompile your code using the version of GCC that corresponds to their GLIBCXX version.
In that case, you can do the following:

1. Look up the latest version of GLIBCXX supported by the target machine: `strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC` ... Say the version is `3.4.19`.
2. Use https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html to find the corresponding GCC version. In our case, this is `[4.8.3, 4.9.0)`.

Answer (score 2):

I have just faced with similar issue building LLVM 3.7 version. 
first check whether you have installed the required library on your system:

```
$locate libstdc++.so.6.*
```

Then add the found location to your $LD_LIBRARY_PATH  environment variable.

Comment: This only works, if you have a libstdc++.so.6.* lib with GLIBCXX_3.4.15  support

Answer (score 1):

I got same error. This is how it worked for me:

- cleaned the project under currently installed gcc
- recompiled it

Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

For this error, I copied the latest libstdc++.so.6.0.17 from other server, and removed the soft link and recreated it. 

1. Copy the the libstdc++.so.6.0.15 or latest from other server to the affected system.
In my case SUSE linux 11 SP3 had latest. 
2. rm libstdc++.so.6 
3. ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.17 libstdc++.so.6 (under /usr/lib64 directory).

nJoy

Answer (score 0):

**Bug with GLIBCXX_3.4.14**
You need to install a newer version of GCC.
http://pkgs.org/download/libstdc++.so.6
goto:

http://geeksterminal.com/how-to-install-glib-glibc/1392/

and follow instructions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem because I changed the user from myself to someone else:

su

For some reason, after did the normal compiling I was not able to execute it (the same error message). Directly ssh to the other user account works.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question.

Comment: No it does because I had the exact same problem. It was caused by changing user. It could also have happened to someone else, say changing to root.

Comment: My mistake! I was thrown by the first line, which looked like you also had the problem. Carry on!

Comment: I also used Ubuntu and also tried to compile programs and also got the same error message as in the question. My error was that I was doing it in another user account by using the su command. I think this answers the question because it addresses why and how about the problem. It's certainly a possibility.

Comment: And one user had LD_LIBRARY_PATH set to find the newer lib but not the other user? That seems a bit far fetched in the specific context of this question.

Comment: I really didn't expect my little attempt to the question would have caused such a big fuss.I can't explain why it was like that, but it was indeed the case. I still believe my answer is valid because it attempts to give a possible solution which might happen if someone attempted to su to root and do some compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple versions of the gcc compiler installed and needed to use a more recent version than the default installation. Since I am not a system administrator for our Linux systems, I cannot just change /usr/lib or many of the other suggestions above. I was encountering this problem and eventually tracked it down to setting my path to the 32-bit library directory instead of the 64-bit library (lib64) directory. Since the libraries in the 32-bit directory were incompatible, the system defaulted to the older version which was out of date.

Using -L to the path I was referencing gave warnings about "skipping incompatible libstdc++.so when searching for -lstdc++". This was the hint that helped me finally resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

gcc version 4.8.1, the error seems like:

> /root/bllvm/build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-tblgen:
>   /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
>   (required by /root/bllvm/build/Release+Asserts/bin/llvm-tblgen)

I found the libstdc++.so.6.0.18 at the place where I complied gcc 4.8.1

Then I do like this

```
cp ~/objdir/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/libstdc++-v3/src/.libs/libstdc++.so.6.0.18 /usr/lib64/

rm /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6

ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.18 libstdc++.so.6
```

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've extracted them from an RPM ([RPM for libstdc++](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/RPM/opensuse/updates/leap/42.1/oss/x86_64/libstdc++6-5.3.1+r233831-6.1.x86_64.html)) and then:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.
```

To set the system to search for the libraries on the current directory. Then just executed my program. But in my case I've received a single executable that I needed, it wasn't a system wide change.

Answer (score 0):

In my case LD_LIBRARY_PATH had /usr/lib64 first before /usr/local/lib64.  (I was builing llvm 3.9).
The new gcc compiler that I installed to compile llvm 3.9 had libraries using  newer GLIBCXX libraries under /usr/local/lib64 So I fixed LD_LIBRARY_PATH for the linker to see /usr/local/lib64 first.
That solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just used -static-libstdc++ while building.
w/ that, I can run the a.out

```
g++ test.cpp -static-libstdc++
```

Answer (score -1):

I've had a similar issue, and I've resolved it by statically linking `libstdc++` into the program I was compiling, like so:

```
$ LIBS=-lstdc++ ./configure ... etc.
```

instead of the usual

```
$ ./configure ... etc.
```

There might be problems with this solution to do with loading shared libraries at runtime, but I haven't looked into the issue deeply enough to comment.

Answer (score -1):

Same thing with gcc version `4.8.1 (GCC)` and `libstdc++.so.6.0.18`. Had to copy it here `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` on my ubuntu box.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem before, and fixed that, the steps could be found on this 
[Fixing error "GLIBCXX_3.4.15" on matlab](http://zijunweihz.wordpress.com/2013/10/09/fixed-matlab-error-usrlocalmatlabr2012abinglnxa64libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx_3-4-15-not-found/)

Answer (score -1):

For testing purposes:

On the original machine, find the library, copy to the same directory as the executable:

```
$ ldconfig -p | grep libstdc
        libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
        libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6
$ cp /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 .
```

Then copy this same library to the target machine, and run the executable:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./myexecutable
```

Note: command above is temporary; it is not a system-wide change.