# Cloog-ppl make error

Tags: gcc, polyhedra

I'm trying to install cloog-ppl 0.15-11 in my 64 bit ubuntu 10.10. I get the following error during make. I guess it is wrt linking.

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I./include/cloog -I./include -I./include   -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -g -O2 -MT cloog.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/cloog.Tpo -c -o cloog.o `test -f 'source/cloog.c' || echo './'`source/cloog.c
mv -f .deps/cloog.Tpo .deps/cloog.Po
/bin/bash ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -g -O2   -o cloog cloog.o libcloog.la -lgmp -lppl_c -lppl -lgmpxx 
libtool: link: gcc -Wall -fomit-frame-pointer -g -O2 -o .libs/cloog cloog.o  ./.libs/libcloog.so /usr/lib/libgmp.so -lppl_c -lppl /usr/lib/libgmpxx.so
//usr/local/lib/libppl_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_unhook()@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
//usr/local/lib/libppl_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_hook(std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
//usr/local/lib/libppl_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::swap(std::__detail::_List_node_base&, std::__detail::_List_node_base&)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
//usr/local/lib/libppl_c.so: undefined reference to `std::__detail::_List_node_base::_M_transfer(std::__detail::_List_node_base*, std::__detail::_List_node_base*)@GLIBCXX_3.4.15'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [cloog] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/praveen/cloog-ppl-0.15.11'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can some one help me out on this ?

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem that I worked for a whole day!! I have a hit, as least this bug disappeared. 
When it refers to `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` it means that you are using a g++ or gcc with the library not providing the functions or classes you need, very likely 4.4 or 4.5. I changed my g++ and gcc to 4.6 and the problem was solved. For some references, you can check out the following:

[How standard lib linked by libstdc++.so.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) 
Notice: I only get libstdc++.so.5 in /usr/lib when I have g++-4.5 installed. I think libstdc++ is the library that g++ and gcc used.

for changing the compiler version in Linux, see the following link:

[Upgrade your compiler](https://superuser.com/questions/310809/how-can-i-update-gcc-to-the-latest-version-in-ubuntu-10-04)

Hope it helps!