# How do you find what version of libstdc++ library is installed on your linux machine?

Tags: c++, linux, shared-libraries

I found the following command: `strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found). It seems to work but this is an ad-hoc/heuristic method.

Is there a specific command that can be used to query the library version of C++? Or is the method I found the accepted method?

Answer (score 113):

To find which library is being used you could run

```
 $ /sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
```

The list of compatible versions for libstdc++ version 3.4.0 and above is provided by

```
 $ strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep LIBCXX
 GLIBCXX_3.4
 GLIBCXX_3.4.1
 GLIBCXX_3.4.2
 ...
```

For earlier versions the symbol `GLIBCPP` is defined.

The date stamp of the library is defined in a macro `__GLIBCXX__` or `__GLIBCPP__` depending on the version:

```
// libdatestamp.cxx
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
#ifdef __GLIBCPP__
    std::printf("GLIBCPP: %d\n",__GLIBCPP__);
#endif
#ifdef __GLIBCXX__
    std::printf("GLIBCXX: %d\n",__GLIBCXX__);
#endif
   return 0;
}

$ g++ libdatestamp.cxx -o libdatestamp
$ ./libdatestamp
GLIBCXX: 20101208
```

The table of datestamps of libstdc++ versions is listed in the [documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html#abi.versioning):

Comment: The datestamps are almost entirely useless, I don't know why we bother keeping them or documenting them.  For example, the date for GCC 4.6.3 is later than 4.7.0, but 4.7.0 has more features, so what use is knowing the date it was released?

Comment: How to install this `strings` command? From which package in come from?

Comment: @user `strings` is a part of GNU binutils.

Comment: It can be short form to 
`strings $(/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++|awk -F'=>' '{print $2}')|grep LIBCXX`

Answer (score 22):

What exactly do you want to know?

The shared library soname? That's part of the filename, `libstdc++.so.6`, or shown by `readelf -d /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep soname`.

The minor revision number?  You should be able to get that by simply checking what the symlink points to:

```
$ ls -l  /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 19 Mar 23 09:43 /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.16
```

That tells you it's 6.0.16, which is the 16th revision of the `libstdc++.so.6` version, which corresponds to the `GLIBCXX_3.4.16` symbol versions.

Or do you mean the release it comes from?  It's part of GCC so it's the same version as GCC, so unless you've screwed up your system by installing unmatched versions of `g++` and `libstdc++.so` you can get that from:

```
$ g++ -dumpversion
4.6.3
```

Or, on most distros, you can just ask the package manager. On my Fedora host that's

```
$ rpm -q libstdc++
libstdc++-4.6.3-2.fc16.x86_64
libstdc++-4.6.3-2.fc16.i686
```

As other answers have said, you can map releases to library versions by checking [the ABI docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)

Comment: "ask the package manager" is a good approach. On Debian 9 I run `apt list libstdc++6`
and get `libstdc++6/oldoldstable,oldoldstable,now 6.3.0-18+deb9u1 amd64 [installed]`

Answer (score 17):

The mechanism I tend to use is a combination of `readelf -V` to dump the `.gnu.version` information from libstdc++, and then a lookup table that matches the largest `GLIBCXX_` value extracted.

```
readelf -sV /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | sed -n 's/.*@@GLIBCXX_//p' | sort -u -V | tail -1
```

if your version of `sort` is too old to have the `-V` option (which sorts by version number) then you can use:

```
tr '.' ' ' | sort -nu -t ' ' -k 1 -k 2 -k 3 -k 4 | tr ' ' '.'
```

instead of the `sort -u -V`, to sort by up to 4 version digits.

In general, matching the ABI version should be good enough.

If you're trying to track down the `libstdc++.so.<VERSION>`, though, you can use a little bash like:

```
file=/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
while [ -h $file ]; do file=$(ls -l $file | sed -n 's/.*-> //p'); done
echo ${file#*.so.}
```

so for my system this yielded `6.0.10`.

If, however, you're trying to get a binary that was compiled on systemX to work on systemY, then these sorts of things will only get you so far. In those cases, carrying along a copy of the libstdc++.so that was used for the application, and then having a run script that does an:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=<directory of stashed libstdc++.so>
exec application.bin "$@"
```

generally works around the issue of the .so that is on the box being incompatible with the version from the application. For more extreme differences in environment, I tend to just add all the dependent libraries until the application works properly. This is the linux equivalent of working around what, for windows, would be considered *dll hell*.

Comment: Can you use `ident` or `what` on the library file to find embedded version info?

Comment: `ident` does the loose equivalent of a `strings -a <file> | grep '\$.*\$'`, `what` uses the equivalent of `strings -a <file> | fgrep '@(#)'`, neither of which determine version information of the underlying library if those strings are not compiled in. Relying on the ABI information makes a lot more sense if you're trying to determine compatibility, as it is generally boiled into the build, while ident/what strings have a tendency to be omitted

Answer (score 11):

You could use `g++ --version` in combination with [the GCC ABI docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html) to find out.