# How can I know the libstdc++ version shipped with each gcc version?

Tags: gcc, libstdc++

How can I know the libstdc++ version shipped with each gcc version? Is there an an easy way to get this info without the need to install the gcc?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354636/how-do-you-find-what-version-of-libstdc-library-is-installed-on-your-linux-mac

Answer (score 7):

You look in the manual, specifically at http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html which shows the library version numbers for each GCC release.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the GCC source code, for example the `libstdc++/ChangeLog` file that comes with it. It shouldn't be too hard to script that.

At first sight, libstdc++ isn't getting real version numbers anymore, they just use the source code repository revision id in the ChangeLog files.

Comment: I need to check the libstdc++ used with some old versions like gcc 4.3.2 and 4.3.4. I tired downloading the source code from ftp://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/misc/gcc/snapshots but couldn't find a directory named libstdc++