# How can I find libstdc++.so.6?

Tags: libstdc++

I'm trying to build Android project on my 64-bit kubuntu linux and encountered the error
message:

error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.

running apt-get install libstdc++6 told me that this library is allready installed on my machine and its up to date. Now I'm trying to find out where it is so I could update my path and tell adb where to look for it.

Tried ;/$ find libstdc++6 and which libstdc++6 and they both failed to find it.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354636/how-do-you-find-what-version-of-libstdc-library-is-installed-on-your-linux-mac) suggests to use bash in order to find libstdc, but it implies 
the library is under \usr\lib which is not my case. I tried "ls \usr\lib\std* " and got "No such file or directory" as a reply.

What else should I do?

Comment: Well, still can't find where is libstdc++ , but according to askubuntu.com:[link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/147400/problems-with-eclipse-and-android-sdk),
one solution is to instal the 32-bit version of libstdc. It works for me.

Comment: The link Ron posted gave me everything I needed to get adb running.