# mask_array behavior in libstdc++

Tags: c++, c++11, libstdc++, valarray

case 1:

```
std::valarray<int> data = {1,4,0,2,5};
std::valarray<bool> exp_mask = data <= 2;
std::mask_array<int> marr1 = data[mask];
marr1 = 10;
```

case 2:

```
std::valarray<int> data = {1,4,0,2,5};
data[data <= 2] = 11; // 7
```

case 3:

```
std::valarray<int> data = {1,4,0,2,5};
std::mask_array<int> marr2 = data[data <= 2];
marr2 = 12;
```

Case 1 and case 2 both work as expected (data is appropriately modified). However, case 3 fails horribly and unreliably (for me it segfaulted). Upon further inspection with gdb, it looks like the internally stored mask points to the buffer of the temporary `data <= 2` valarray, which gets destroyed after line 2. Then when line 3 goes to do the write the mask is complete garbage, and trying to index into it to set the masked values of data is undefined behavior.

I can't find anywhere in the standard why this behavior is allowed (the standard is strangely vague about valarray). Is this libstdc++'s faux pas, or should I expect this result and why?

Compiler settings tested:

- g++4.8.2 -O0 -g -std=c++0x
- clang++ -O0 -g -std=c++11

I believe my version of libstdc++ is 3.4.19 (just followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10355215/558546) to find it)

Comment: I think the problem is libstdc++'s bug. You should report bug. https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/

Comment: Done: [bug #63314](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=63314). I also found that the same type of problem happens with indirect_array