# What could cause clang to not find the unordered_map header?

Tags: c++, header-files, clang++

I'm trying to compile a program I found on the web using Clang++. The Makefile generates this command:

```
clang++ -c -arch x86_64 -msse3 -std=c++11 -stdlib=libstdc++
-Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wreturn-type
-Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-exit-time-destructors -Wformat -Wmissing-braces
-Wparentheses -Wno-switch -Wunused-function -Wunused-label -Wno-unused-parameter
-Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wno-empty-body -Wuninitialized -Wunknown-pragmas
-Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion
-Wint-conversion -Wno-shorten-64-to-32 -Wenum-conversion -Wno-newline-eof
-Wno-c++11-extensions -Wno-logical-op-parentheses -Wno-trigraphs
-Wno-invalid-offsetof -Wno-sign-conversion -Wdeprecated-declarations
-fmessage-length=0 -fno-exceptions -fstrict-aliasing -fvisibility=hidden
-fvisibility-inlines-hidden -funsafe-math-optimizations -ftrapping-math -fno-rtti
-fpascal-strings -fasm-blocks -O3 -Iinclude/ src/main.cpp
```

But I get

```
src/main.cpp:23:10: fatal error: 'unordered_map' file not found
#include <unordered_map>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

If I compile a simple program that includes `<unordered_map>` running `clang++ test.cpp`, it **compiles fine**.

I'm on

```
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: If you compile your simple test program with `clang++ (those options) test.cpp`, it'll fail too. At that point, you can simply start removing options to see which is the one that causes the problem. (Start from the front. It's one of the first.)

Comment: Strange that `clang++ test.cpp` compiles, as `<unordered_map>` requires C++11 (`-std=c++11`)...

Comment: What is the version of your libstdc++? Did you compile `test.cpp` with libstdc++ as well?

Comment: @Jarod42 Just tried it again, it compiles without any problems.

Comment: @hvd Thanks, I followed your advice and it seems to be `-stdlib=libstdc++`

Comment: @user2079303 That is the root of the problem indeed! How can I check the version of `libstdc++`?

Comment: @NiklasR check this answer for that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10355215/2079303

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue when compiling glogg.

As the comments have pointed out. it was stdlib.

In the makefile after running qmake. Change this line from

```
CXXFLAGS      = -g -Wextra -std=c++11 -DGLOGG_VERSION=\"`cat .tarball-version`\" -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
```

To this line below

```
CXXFLAGS      = -g -Wextra -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -DGLOGG_VERSION=\"`cat .tarball-version`\" -O2 -arch x86_64 -Wall -W $(DEFINES)
```

notice "-stdlib=libc++" was specified in the cxxflags. It's autospecified in the linker flags, I guess it also needs to be specified in for the C++ flags.

Answer (score -3):

It says -Wno-c++11-extensions. What wrote that makefile?

Comment: `-W` is an option which controls warnings. How is it relevant?