# unordered_map not found

Tags: c++, qt, stl, include

I need to use a .cpp file which contains `#include <unordered_map>` in a Qt project (Based on Qt 5.4.2 (Clang 6.0 (Apple), 64 bit)). However, I got the
error: 'unordered_map' file not found. I had checked the path of the folder where `unordered_map` header file locates is the same as `<algorithm>`, 
`<utility>`, `<iostream>`, and `<sstream>` which are included in the beginning of the same .cpp file. Only 'unordered_map' cannot be found. Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you enabled C++11 (or later)? If there's no checkbox in the project settings, manually add the flag `-std=c++11`.

Comment: look if https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26233011/what-could-cause-clang-to-not-find-the-unordered-map-header can solve your problem

Comment: Qt provides [QHash](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qhash.html#details), I would use it instead `unordered_map`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add`config +=c++11` in pro file

You can refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16948382/how-to-enable-c11-in-qt-creator).

Answer (score 1):

The `std::unordered_map` template class was added in C++11, so you are probably not compiling with C++11 support. This is especially true considering that `<algorithm>`, `<utility>`, `<iostream>` and `<sstream>` work just fine (which all existed before C++11).

Simply add the `-std=c++11` flag while compiling.

Comment: Yes you are right. Thank you!