# libstdc++ doesn't recognise standard library literals

Tags: c++, clang, libstdc++

I'm trying to compile a simple program utilizing literals from the `std::literals` namespace, but Clang is generating errors when I try to compile it.

The code I'm trying to compile:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::literals;

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!"s << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

and the compilation command:

```
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++1y a.cpp
```

which leads to this output:

```
a.cpp:4:22: error: expected namespace name
using namespace std::literals;
                ~~~~~^
a.cpp:8:29: error: no matching literal operator for call to 'operator "" s' with arguments of
      types 'const char *' and 'unsigned long', and no matching literal operator template
        std::cout << "Hello World!"s << std::endl;
                                   ^
2 errors generated.
```

Using g++ or libc++ are out of the question for various reasons, and I've confirmed that other C++14 features (ie. return type deduction and binary literals) work, so it's not an issue with the compiler, making me believe it involves libstdc++.

What can I do to fix this? I'm on Linux Mint 17.1 if it makes any difference.

Comment: libstdc++ has support for this, so you must have an older version.

Comment: Is there a way for me to check the version that I have installed?

Comment: You could follow the advice [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354636/how-do-you-find-what-version-of-libstdc-library-is-installed-on-your-linux-mac), but it's likely the same as GCC, so `gcc --version` should give the same answer.

Comment: g++'s version is showing as 4.8.4

Answer (score 3):

Remember to ensure that you're compiling the source according to C++14 (the chrono literals are not provided in C++11).

```
clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++14 a.cpp
```