# clang++-17 with -std=c++20 can't find zoned_time in namespace 'std::chrono'

Tags: c++, clang++, c++-chrono

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```cpp
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const std::chrono::zoned_time zt{ "Europe/London", std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
    std::cout << zt << '\n';
}
```

In order to do so I'm using the following command: `clang++-17 -std=c++20 test_chrono_tz.cpp`

The output of this on my machine is:

```
test_chrono_tz.cpp:6:24: error: no type named 'zoned_time' in namespace 'std::chrono'
    6 |     const std::chrono::zoned_time zt{ "Europe/London", std::chrono::system_clock::now() };
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
1 error generated.
```

However this works on Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/187o4TP7z

The output of `clang++-17 --version` is:

```
Ubuntu clang version 17.0.1 (++20230919093346+e19b7dc36bc0-1~exp1~20230919093406.44)
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
```

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.
How can I get `std::chrono::zoned_time` to work?

Comment: According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support#C.2B.2B20_library_features), clang only offers partial support for C++20 `std::chrono` additions. Nothing you can do except for changing to a different standard library implementation, different compiler altogether or you could offer help and submit pull request to libc++ with implementation.

Comment: Neither clang nor gcc lists their implementation status of P0355.  That's annoying.

Comment: You're using libstdc++, which version of that are you using, only 14 has full support

Comment: @AlanBirtles These are unchartered waters for me (hence me asking), so I googled and found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10354636/how-do-you-find-what-version-of-libstdc-library-is-installed-on-your-linux-mac. If this is wrong, let me know what information you need. The output of running `/sbin/ldconfig -p | grep stdc++` gives me ```    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x32) => /libx32/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
    libstdc++.so.6 (libc6) => /lib32/libstdc++.so.6```

Comment: The version of libstdc++ usually matches gcc. If I'm using clang, I prefer to use their standard library implementation, libc++.