# What does "/usr/lib/libstdc .so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found" mean, and how do I fix it?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries

I'm new to compiling libraries `.so` under Ubuntu. I have the source, `.cpp` file. I installed the build-essentials package finely, and I'm using the Anjuta IDE to compile the source code. I have the Makefile and everything is good.

Now although it compiles without error, when I load it, I get the error:

```
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found`
```

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

Edit: Any more tips?

Edit2: I really need help guys.

Comment: Have you installed the `libstdc++6` package? That might fix it.

Comment: Yes I have it installed. I'm now running the command Gung Foo posted. Will update later if it fixes or not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.15' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issues and I tried (https://askubuntu.com/questions/164296/glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found):

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

optionally you can force a global update of all the linked libraries with

```
sudo ldconfig
```

this last command can take some time and will not print anything on the bash, just wait.

Comment: Here's what I get when I do that:
`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libstdc++6 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 5 not upgraded.`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a dependency problem, is your system up to date?

```
apt-get install && apt-get upgrade
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to work around this issue is to simply link libstdc++ statically (with this parameter sent to g++ when linking the executable):

```
-static-libstdc++
```

If linking in the library statically is an option this is probably the quickest work-around.