# "/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found`", how to fix it?

Tags: c++

I'm compiling a `.so` under Ubuntu using the Anjuta IDE. Even though it compiles fine, when I load the `.so`, it throws that error:

`/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found`

I found that running the command:

`strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX` would print the version you have installed, but it gives me the error: `strings: '/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6': No such file`

Any of you guys have any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you see [this question?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/164296/glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found). Also, this question is probably better for that site (askubuntu).

Comment: Thanks. Will give it a try, if it fails to fix it will ask on that site.

Comment: If you're in 64-bit, try `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.15' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

Answer (score 0):

Try running: `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6`