# Where can I get a copy of the file libstdc++.so.6.0.15

Tags: c++, file, find, libstdc++

I am trying to fix my problem "GLIBCXX_3.4.15" not found, which is fairly well documented to fix. But it requires getting the file "libstdc++.so.6.0.15" from somewhere.

Most of the solutions tell me to get it from the location that I compiled my c++ library from. However, I did not compile it, it came with my Ubuntu installation, and when I do "locate" for that file it is not found.

So, I would like to just download it from somewhere, but I can't find it on the web anywhere. I have tried to look in the svn repo: svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc, but was not able to find it (its huge!)

Any help much appreciated :)
Fodder

Comment: [Someone else had this problem before.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

Comment: I know, I mentioned that the issue will fairly well documented. But I don't have that file on my PC, I just want to get a copy of it from somewhere.... the only answer I need is a location of where the file can be gotten from :)    (EDIT: sorry, bit harsh, thanks for the link though!)

Comment: @code_fodder You shouldn't (and probably can't) get a binary version of it. You should either get it from your distribution repository, or compiling it yourself from source.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You shouldn't have to manually download this library, if you're on Ubuntu Linux, it should be shipped inside this package :

```
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

If you already have `libstdc++6`, then the problem is elsewhere and you should explain what you're trying to achieve in the first place.

If you want a newer version of `libstdc++6` than the one provided in the default package, then you can try to update to the *toolchain* test package :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Otherwise you would have to compile GCC from source :

- Install the prerequisite (using `sudo apt-get build-dep gcc-4.7` as instance)
- Get the source from [GNU.org](http://gcc.gnu.org/mirrors.html)
- Compile it using `configure`, `make` and `make install`

Comment: I have it installed, but I need a newer version to install Qt5.0.2. My version has libstdc++.so.6.0.14, I just need the newer version.

Comment: @code_fodder I added information on how to update `libstdc++`.

Comment: ok... I give in, I will have to just update to get the whole newer compiler! :o, thanks all for answers / comments

Comment: do you have any idea how to install this on arch linux?

Answer (score 1):

Just realized that was having the similar problem some time ago. *Disclaimer*: If you know what you are doing, check this repository - [Index of /debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7](http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7/). It must be in some of the packages available. Use Archive Manager to get inside.