# Which Ubuntu package needs to be installed to use ModernIE Vms?

Tags: internet-explorer, ubuntu, modern.ie

I have downloaded the `.sfx` file for IE8 from modern.ie and followed the instructions on the site, to give the file executable permission.  But when running it I get an error about a missing shared library.

```
./IE8.WinXP.For.LinuxVirtualBox.sfx: error while loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I'm running desktop Ubuntu 13.04, 64-bit, and Virtual Box 4.2.10

Does anyone know which package I should install?  I've already run `sudo apt-get install libstdc++6` (as suggested [elsewhere on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15)) but that has not helped.

Comment: people on this thread said they had to run dpkg --add-architecture i386" and "apt-get update" as well -- http://www.hellotecho.com/ubuntu-extracting-sfx-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just had the same problem. I got this working, you need two libraries

```
sudo apt-get install libc6-i386 
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
```