# Genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: not found

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, genymotion

I am trying to run Genymotion and what I got is:

```
./genymotion: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found
```

And when I check in the folder */usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/*, the file *libstdc++.so.6* is there. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Your title is misleading. The error message doesn't say that the file is missing, it says that it is too old. Where does this genymotion binary come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you that check if the installer you downloaded is compatible with the version of Linux distribution.

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

You can solve of libs at the following link:
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15?answertab=oldest#tab-top)