# Microsoft SQL Server ODBC driver on Linux Ubuntu 14.04: wrong library version

Tags: sql-server, linux, ubuntu-14.04

I was unable to connect to a MS-SQL server via Microsoft's ODBC driver for Linux. Error messages below:

```
isql mydsn myuser mypw -v

[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0' : file not found
```

The message above isn't telling the whole story though. Let's see what **ldd** can tell us:

```
ldd /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0
/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0)
/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.8' not found (required by /opt/microsoft/msodbcsql/lib64/libmsodbcsql-13.0.so.0.0)
        [...]
```

(I'm installing this on a Docker image so that [Caravel](https://github.com/airbnb/caravel) can connect to MS-SQL databases - see [Dockerfile](https://github.com/elifarley/caravel/blob/MS-SQL/Dockerfile), [Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/elifarley/caravel/tags/) for Caravel)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commands below will install the correct version of **libstdc++.so.6** (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15)):

```
echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu trusty main' > \
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1E9377A2BA9EF27F
apt-get update -y
apt-get upgrade -y
apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

So if you're starting from scratch on ubuntu 14.04, these commands will install UnixODBC, Microsoft SQL Server ODBC driver for Linux and all required dependencies:

```
echo 'deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-toolchain-r/test/ubuntu trusty main' > \
    /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu-toolchain-r-test-trusty.list && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 1E9377A2BA9EF27F && \
    apt-get update -y && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y build-essential libssl-dev libffi-dev \
    curl ca-certificates libgss3 && \
    locale-gen en_US.utf8 && dpkg-reconfigure locales

mkdir -p /tmp/ms-sql && (cd /tmp/ms-sql && curl 'https://download.microsoft.com/download/2/E/5/2E58F097-805C-4AB8-9FC6-71288AB4409D/msodbcsql-13.0.0.0.tar.gz' \
  -H 'Referer: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=50419' --compressed | \
  tar --strip-components=1 -xzv && \
  sed -ri -e 's/wget/curl/g' -e's/(\s*)\$\(curl[^)]+\)/\1curl -fsSL "$dm_url" -o "$dm_package_path"/' \
  -e '/make install/,$ d' build_dm.sh && echo '(cd $tmp/$dm_dir && make install)' >> build_dm.sh && \
  echo YES | ./build_dm.sh --accept-warning --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu && \
  ./install.sh install --accept-license) && \
  sed -rie 's/\[.+SQL Server\]/[MS-SQL]/' /etc/odbcinst.ini
```