# Unable to properly install or load Tensorflow on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with resultant ImportError

Tags: python, ubuntu, tensorflow, anaconda

I attempted the [Anaconda installation](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/get_started/os_setup.html#anaconda-installation) for TensorFlow on my Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system, which went through, but while importing the library in Python, I came across an ImportError shown below.

I went through a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33655731/error-while-importing-tensorflow-in-python2-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-glibc-2-17-not-f) given for a similar thread, but it didn't work for me.

Basically here's what I did for the installation:

```
$ conda create -n tensorflow python=2.7
$ source activate tensorflow
(tensorflow)$ conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow
(tensorflow)$ source deactivate
$ source activate tensorflow
```

Then from within the virtualenv I loaded Python, and tried to import tensorflow. What I got was the following error:

```
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/anirudh/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/anirudh/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 48, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/home/anirudh/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
_pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/home/anirudh/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
 ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /home/anirudh/anaconda/envs/tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

How do I sort this?

Comment: Why do you insist on a four year old OS release?

Comment: It so happens that my computer hardware isn't compatible for a software upgrade. An upgrade causes the graphic drivers to fail on reboot. I have a Dell Vostro 3445 Notebook.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install [libstdc++6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libstdc++6) with some dependencies like `gcc` an `g++`, at least `gcc-4.6` version:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gcc-4.9 g++-4.9
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6
```

Or you can install `linux-headers` and `build-essential` witch contains some useful tools like `gcc` compiler, `make` .... tools for compiling and building software from source.

Answer (score 0):

This error probably relates to you glibc version. There are some topics regarding this:[Where can I get a copy of the file libstdc++.so.6.0.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15)

First check whether the required version is on your system.

```
    $ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

If it is not listed, you can try

```
    $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
    $ sudo apt-get update
    $ sudo apt-get upgrade
    $ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

"sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" may not be required.

Answer (score 0):

It happened for me in CentOS 7

Running python script in conda environment I got very similar error about "GLIBCXX_3.4.22..." required by tensorflow wrapper.

In my case first I did was:

"conda install libgcc"

Some libraries were installed, but that didn't helped me. I finally solved the issue by deleting "GLIBCXX" from the folder that came with Schroedinger maestro software that was installed earlier. I think, there was some sort of conflict between two libraries.