# ImportError: scipy/spatial/ckdtree.so

Tags: python, scipy, anaconda, libstdc++

I'm using `Anaconda2 v5.0.1` on `LinuxMint 17.3 Rosa`. When I tried to `import scipy.stats` I got this error:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `CXXABI_1.3.9' not found (required by /home/dolf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/_sparsetools.so
```

Then I tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16605759/836995):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

But now I get this error:

```
ImportError: /home/dolf/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/spatial/ckdtree.so: symbol _ZTINSt8ios_base7failureB5cxx11E, version GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not defined in file libstdc++.so.6 with link time reference
```

I don't understand the error message, and cannot find anything useful online. How can I fix this?

Comment: Read [this](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/5191#issuecomment-338474902). Not my area of expertise, but to me it sounds like: either upgrade your OS or user anaconda < 5.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. That may explain why it does work on my other computer running LinuxMint 18.2.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out thanks to @sascha's comment on the question.

First, remove the PPA if you added it:

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
```

Then downgrade anaconda to something below 5:

```
conda install anaconda=4
```