# Tensorflow bazel build

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

I try compile tensorflow in debian.
I follow this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_recognition#usage_with_the_c_api

I run:

```
bazel build tensorflow/examples/label_image/...
```

And errors:

```
/usr/bin/bazel: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /usr/bin/bazel)
/usr/bin/bazel: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /usr/bin/bazel)
/usr/bin/bazel: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /usr/bin/bazel)
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I get a copy of the file libstdc++.so.6.0.15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605623/where-can-i-get-a-copy-of-the-file-libstdc-so-6-0-15)

Comment: This topic doesn't solve my problem.