# Phusion Passenger with Apache troubleshooting - openSSL load error, link time reference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, openssl, passenger

I'm past all this now and trying to fix the problem not in quotes down below, but leaving for background information.

> I am trying to get a working rails development environment on my LAMP
>   stack, so I've installed rbenv, the 2.1.2 version of ruby, the 4.1.4
>   version of Rails and the phusion mod for Apache. I'm now seeing very
>   strange errors when I try to stop and start my Apache service and I
>   think the issue is that Phusion has rebuilt the Apache installation on
>   the machine and Apache is now looking for configuration files in
>   `/etc/apache2/`. I'm now struggling to find out how to fix apache to
>   look in the LAMP directories for `httpd.conf`.
>
> Here are some examples of the errors.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                               
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.


$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
Restarting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.3-4...
XAMPP: Stopping Apache...fail.
apachectl returned 1.
XAMPP: Stopping MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Stopping ProFTPD...not running.
XAMPP: Starting Apache...already running.
XAMPP: Starting MySQL...ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD...fail.
XAMPP:  Another FTP daemon is already running.
```

> Also, this is how I've modified the config file in
>   `/opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf`. I know the module is supposed to be a .so
>   file but I did not see one in my directory (didn't really spend enough
>   time looking into this to know how to fix it, do I need to compile
>   something?)

```
LoadModule passenger_module /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.c
PassengerRoot /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45
PassengerRuby /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/bin/ruby
```

> Server is running Ubuntu 14.04. Install order was LAMP (1.8.3-4), Ruby
>   1.9.3 (via apt-get), then rbenv, then ruby-build, then installed Ruby 2.1.2, then removed Ruby 1.9.3 via apt-get remove, then installed rails gems, then installed phusion for Apache and the ruby gem for
>   phusion.
>
> Edit 1: I found out it's actually an issue with my LoadModule file
>   paths
>
> I checked out the actual LAMPP script to see where the apachectl
>   returned 1 error was coming from and it was just running
>   /opt/lampp/bin/apachectl, so then I ran the same command
>   `/opt/lampp/bin/apachectl -k stop` and it gave me a very descriptive
>   error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 160 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.c into server: /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/ext/apache2/mod_passenger.c: invalid ELF header
```

> Commented out my lines-need to figure out how to get the appropriate
>   .so file.

Edit 2:
I ran the passenger-install-apache2-module installer and it seemed to work fine and told me the lines to add to my program (including the .so file which I was missing before)

Now I'm running into a far more confusing error that I think is related to the version of GCC that is available for ubuntu 14.04 and I can't find any resources on the internet that deal with this problem

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 160 of /opt/lampp/etc/httpd.conf: Cannot load /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so into server: /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.9' not found (required by /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/buildout/apache2/mod_passenger.so)
```

Saw this in another google search to see which GCC versions are available, apparently 3.4.9 isn't one of them (go figure, that's what the error says.) Any ideas on how I can remedy this?

```
$ strings /opt/lampp/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep -i glibcxx
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
```

Edit 3: It's 6 AM and I think I figured it out at last.

I did a few searches and found this post here:
[/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

And then I did a find on the root directory

```
find / | grep -i libstdc++.so
```

And used the strings command I found earlier-the libstdc++.so had GLIBCXX_3.4.9 in the directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19` so I backed up the old one with mv and copied the new one to the lampp directory. Restarted the server and got no errors. Supposedly I have a working rails stack now :)

Edit 4:
Welp, Phusion is working, but there's a new problem... Now when I navigate to my new virtual host (RailsEnv set to development) I get this lovely stack trace on a bunch of code I have no experience with. Seems like something's wrong with the sha1.so referencing some unknown symbol that's supposed to be in libcrypto.so.1.0.0. What the heck is link time reference?

Interestingly, if I just navigate to the application folder and do rails server, I can see the application without issue. Does the application need to be generated? (i.e. call rails generate)?

```
/home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so: symbol SHA1_Init, version OPENSSL_1.0.0 not defined in file libcrypto.so.1.0.0 with link time reference - /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so (LoadError)
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/definition.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:153:in `definition'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/bundler-1.6.3/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `require'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:135:in `rescue in require'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:144:in `require'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:258:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:361:in `running_bundler'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/lib/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:256:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /home/moody/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/passenger-4.0.45/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:28:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Web Apps Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

The errors you are getting says that port [:80] is already in use so checking which process has that port occupied and killing that process might be the fix for you. You can do this by running

sudo kill $(sudo lsof -t -i:80)

or

sudo kill `sudo lsof -t -i:9001`

After the process gets terminated, try restarting the apache server.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error like yours which is regarding the OPENSSL version.
You can refer this post. https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/phusion-passenger/6nRi0FU98_g

For my case, I resolved it by changing my apache version to 2.2.22