# R: OS command invoked by "system" can't find library

Tags: r

I am using program [bedtools](http://bedtools.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and it works perfectly when I am invoking it from my OS (`CentOS release 6.4`).
I tried to invoke this program using R `system` and it gave me error:

```
bedtools: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by bedtools)
```

My R version is: `3.0.1 (2013-05-16) -- "Good Sport"`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for not being able to run bedtools from within R is that the shell environment is different from the environment outside R. This is a suggestion for how to track down the difference, but since I don't have access to the actual computer it contains a fair amount of guesswork.

It appears that there are multiple versions of `libstdc++` (needed to run bedtools) on your system. Run the following command to see which ones you have:

```
$ locate libstdc++.so

/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.4/32/libstdc++.so
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
```

Then run [the following command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) on them to see if they differ in versions

```
$ strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC

GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

If you find `GLIBCXX_3.4.15` in one of them, search for its directory among the environment variables outside R to see which it belongs to:

```
$ set | grep "<path>"
```

When you find the right environment variable, add the path to it inside R with `Sys.setenv` as suggested by @morispaa.

```
Sys.setenv(<VARIABLE> = paste0("<path>:", Sys.getenv("<VARIABLE>"))
```

Best of luck!

#### Original answer:

I suspect that you set some environment variable in you `.bashrc` or similar that points out the library, perhaps you add it to your `$PATH`?

As a matter of fact, `system` exectues statements you give it in *new shell session*, in which your `.bashrc` and similar config files are not sourced. As an example, I set the variable `HISTSIZE=1000` in my `.bashrc` and I can view it in bash by typing:

```
~$ echo $HISTSIZE
1000
```

But if I do the same thing in R I get nothing

```
> system("echo $HISTSIZE")
```

On the other hand, if I set it and before echoing it I do get it back (obviously)

```
> system("export HISTSIZE=1000 && echo $HISTSIZE")
1000
```

but after the `system` call is completed it is no longer there if I do another

```
> system("echo $HISTSIZE")
```

Comment: I tried to `system("source ~/.bashrc && bedtools")`, but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you personally install the library or add the path `/usr/lib64` to `$PATH` in some config file? Perhaps it was set up by some administrator and loads in some other way when you start a new session? This really is not my area of expertice though.

Comment: This was set up by admin.

Comment: You can see the environmental variables seen by R by `system("printenv")`and set/alter them using `Sys.setenv()`, for example `Sys.setenv(EDITOR="vim")`.