# /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' required by /lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7

Tags: c++, mysql, c++11

Is it possible that there are 2 versions of libstdc++.so.6 installed, and while compiling it is using a different version

---

In my code I am reading a binary file and storing the data in mysql server.

While compiling the file. The file compiles properly.
Command used for compiling

g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -I/usr/include -o mkt MtkF.cpp -L/usr/lib -lmysqlcppconn

While running the file I get and error as -

```
libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20'  required by /lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21'  required by /lib/libmysqlcppconn.so.7
```

OS CentOS

On running this command -

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep LIBCXX
```

It return values till GLIBC19

Have looked at other solutions also, but no luck.

Comment: your mysql library was built with newer g++ than your libstdc++, upgrade libstdc++ or build your mysql library by the built-in gcc of your distro

Comment: Possible duplicate of [/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.15' not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

Comment: Hi Danh, can you provide me with the command using which I can upgrade to the new library

Comment: is it possible that there are 2 versions of libstdc++.so.6 installed, and while compiling it is using a different version @Danh. Because the file i already updated