# libstdc++ Error: 'GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found

Tags: python, c++, linux, cross-compiling

I was trying to cross-compile dlib for Raspberry Pi, using the arm-linux-gnueabihf compiler.

After successful runs of `cmake` and `make -j4`, I ran `python setup.py bdist_wheel --repackage`, which created the necessary .so files which I later copied to my Pi's `/usr/lib` using `scp`.

Now when I run `import dlib` in IDLE, I get the following error:

`` ImportError: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by dlib/dlib.so) ``

Here's the ouput of `strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX`:

`GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20`

This means that the error is legitimate, but my libstdc++ is already at its newest version on the Pi. What can I do to get that **3.4.22** version installed on the Pi? Or maybe, if it's possible, to compile it again against **3.4.20**? How can I set a compiler flag for that?

*Note:* I posted this on the RaspberryPi SE site, but was suggested to ask it here. [libstdc++ Error](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/72177/libstdc-error-glibcxx-3-4-22-not-found?noredirect=1#comment113566_72177)

Comment: For my case, I add `-static-libstdc++`. For example, `g++ -static-libstdc++ main.cpp`.

Comment: Where does static-libstdc++ live?

Comment: I don't know. Look at here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found

Comment: Doesn't work for dlib. Get a plethora of compiler errors.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use `-static-libstdc++` when linking, see https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options