# Why is version `GLIBCXX_3.4.28' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5)

Tags: python, g++, libstdc++, manjaro

Folks I'm trying to run the [following code](https://github.com/komorin0521/darknet_server) on manjaro linux. But as I start the server with:

```
 python3 darknet_server.py
```

It reports

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "darknet_server.py", line 342, in <module>
    main()
  File "darknet_server.py", line 328, in main
    datafilepath=datafilepath.encode(),
  File "/home/vfbsilva/Source/darknet_alexey/darknet/pythons/darknet.py", line 120, in __init__
    self.lib = CDLL(self.libfilepath, RTLD_GLOBAL)
  File "/home/vfbsilva/Programas/anaconda3/envs/darknet376/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: /home/vfbsilva/Programas/anaconda3/envs/darknet376/lib/python3.7/site-packages/../../libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.28' not found (required by /usr/lib/libQt5Widgets.so.5)
```

But

```
pacman -Qo /lib/libstdc++.so.6
/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 pertence a gcc-libs 10.2.0-2
```

Shows libstdc++.so.6 as installed. What can I do?

Comment: Maybe see if this helps?  (static linkinging libstdc++)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/25482925/13022

Comment: Or also see this:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/575505/glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found-how-to-fix-this-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`darknet376` comes with its own, outdated copy of `libstdc++.so.6`, which overrides the system version (either due to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or some `RPATH` or `RUN_PATH` setting directly in an ELF `.so` file).

You should be able to work around this by simply deleting the `libstdc++.so.6` file (the one in the `darknet376` directory tree, not the system version in `/lib`) because the system version is sufficiently new, so the bundled version is probably not required for running this software.

Comment: I did not try your suggestion so far but I solved it downgrading a lib in conda:
"graphql-core<3"

How could it be a changer?